# Getting a list of enemies to battle one at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was hoping someone might be able to answer my question. For a text based video game I'm making I'm trying to get a list of enemies to battle the hero anytime the hero hits a certain spot on my map. I've created a parent class Character and then two children classes Hero and Enemy. I have a list of enemy names and another list of their corresponding curHp. I'm new to python and am struggling to know where to put the enemy name List and their curHp list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Character (object):

    def __init__(self, name, curHp):
        self.__name = name
        self.__curHp = curHp


    def getName(self):
        return self.__name
    def getCurHp(self):
        return self.__curHp

    def setName(self, newName):
        newName= self.__newName

    def setCurHp(self, newCurHp):
        H = ""
        self.__newCurHp=self.__curHp + 20

class Hero (Character):

    def __init__(self, name, curHp, stun, laser, vsurge):
        super().__init__(name, curHp, stun, laser, vsurge)
        self.__stun=stun
        self.__laser= laser
        self.__vsurge= vsurge


    def getStun(self):
        return self.__stun
    def getLaser(self):
        return self.__laser
    def getVsurge(self):
        return self.__vsurge


    def setStun(self,newStun):
        self.__newStun=self.__newStun
    def setLaser (self,newLaser):
        self.__newLaser= self.__newLaser
    def setVsurge(self, newVsurge):
        self.__newVsurge = self.__vsurge + 25

class Enemy(Character):

    def __init__(self, name, curHp, attack):
        super().__init__(name, curHp, attack)
        self.__attack=attack


    def getAttack(self):
        return self.__attack


    def setAttack (self, newAttack):
        newAttack= self.__newAttack
```

I tried putting the list in def main(): but I keep getting errors

```
player=Hero ("Agent Five", 120, 20 ,10 ,25 )
enemy=Enemy (name=["Raptor", "T-Rex", "Enemy Solider", "General", "Dual Sentience", "Empty Robot", "The Sentience", "GOD"],curHp=[40, 100, 25, 60, 75, 45, 130, 200], []  )

 At line:1 char:2
+ [40, 100, 25, 60, 75, 45, 130, 200]cd 'd:\Time Breakers Game\TimeBrea ...
+  ~
Missing type name after '['.
At line:1 char:4
+ [40, 100, 25, 60, 75, 45, 130, 200]cd 'd:\Time Breakers Game\TimeBrea ...
+    ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],         ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename
```

Any tips would be much appreciated. Thank you

Update: the last empty list in the enemy Lists will eventually be attack points for each enemy.

Comment: As a side note: You almost certainly don't want those double-underscore names like `__hp`. Or getters like `getHp`. And the fact that you're using them is almost always a sign that whoever's teaching you doesn't really know Python and is trying to teach you Java instead, so you should find a better source to learn from. (If it's a teacher in school, there's not much you can do, but if it's a book or online tutorial or video series, just find another one.)

Comment: same as @abarnert's answer. and don't send attack, stun, laser and so on to `super`

Comment: Also, what interpreter are you running this in? Those don't look like errors from CPython, PyPy, Jython, or IronPython.

Comment: @abarnert I am learning from a teacher, and he mentioned we should be doing the __hp for everything we write, but I'll definitely keep it in mind that there is a better way to do it. I am using Visual Studio Code with a Python addition

Comment: @K.Camp Then take it as a warning that your teacher doesn't know what he's doing with Python, and you may want to find better (out-of-class) sources to learn from. Unfortunately, you'll _also_ have to learn his way for a good grade in the class, and keep the differences straight in your head, which makes your life harder. Having a bad teacher isn't actually quite as bad in Python as in, say, set theory or novel writing, because at least it's easier to learn on your own, but it's still a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a list of enemies, you can't call the `Enemy` constructor with list of values; instead, you have to call the `Enemy` constructor once for enemy. You can use `zip` to make this easier.

Also, you can't put positional arguments after keyword arguments—either use `name=…, curHp=…, attack=…` or just `…, …, …`, not `name=…, curHp=…, …`.

Finally, I'm not sure what you wanted that `[]` to do for attack. Maybe 0 for everyone? Whatever you want, you have to say it explicitly.

So:

```
enemy_names = ["Raptor", "T-Rex", "Enemy Solider", "General", "Dual Sentience", "Empty Robot", "The Sentience", "GOD"]
enemy_hps = [40, 100, 25, 60, 75, 45, 130, 200]

enemies = []
for name, hp in zip(enemy_names, enemy_hps):
    enemies.append(Enemy(name, hp, 0))
```

If you know what list comprehensions are, you can probably see that the last three lines can be rewritten:

```
enemies = [Enemy(name, hp, 0) for name, hp in zip(enemy_names, enemy_hps]
```

Or, if you have a list of attacks like the lists of names and hp:

```
enemies = [Enemy(*props) for props in zip(enemy_names, enemy_hps, enemy_attacks)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I hope its okay to ask another question: Should I be putting this list in the enemy class or in def main():?

Comment: @K.Camp In general, another question should be asked as a new question, rather than comments on an answer. But this one is pretty simple, so… I think putting it in `main` makes more sense. The list of enemy names isn't really an attribute of the `Enemy` type, and neither is the list of enemy objects.

Comment: @abarnet My apologies, I didn't know. I'm new to Stack Overflow and am still learning. Thank you again for all of your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a function that returns a dictionary of characters with their HP.

You do not need to declare attack in the **init**

```
class Enemy(Character):

    def __init__(self, name, curHp, attack):
        super().__init__(name, curHp)
        self.__attack = attack

    def enemy_dict(self, names, hps):
        """ Takes in a list of names and a list of HP and returns a dictionary of pairs"""
        return dict(zip(names, hps))
```

To have the enemies attack the player one at a time. call a for loop on the dictionary and in this instance I have used `random.choice` to pick a random amount and then apply it as damage to the player

```
import random

print(player.getName(), player.getCurHp())

for k, v in enemy.enemy_dict(enemy.getName(), enemy.getCurHp()).items():
    att_damage = random.choice(range(0, v, 5))
    if att_damage == 0:
        print('No Damage Taken')
    else:
        new_hp = player.getCurHp() - att_damage
        player.setCurHp(new_hp)
        print(player.getName(), "Took Damage of ", new_hp, "From Enemy", k)\

print(player.getName(), player.getCurHp())
```

You also need to change the setters the other way round in the class modules.

It should read

```
def setName(self, newName):
    self.__newName = newName 

def setCurHp(self, newCurHp):
    H = ""
    self.__curHp = newCurHp
```

Comment: Why would you use `Character.__init__` instead of `super`? That's not idiomatic (and it implies to the reader that this is old Python 2.x code for old-style classes, which isn't true). Also, why would you use an instance method to create a dict of enemies? That means you can't create any enemies until you've already created an enemy. Also, "you have not declared a type for the character so passing in a list is fine"… what does that mean? You seem to be saying that the actually broken part of the OP's code, the part they're getting an error on and asking for help with, is fine?

Comment: Also, why `[i for i in range(v)]` instead of just `range(v)`. And why even create a range to call `choice` on instead of just using `randrange`?